# How to count number of strings with digits in list of lists?

Tags: python

```
list = [['hi0', 'myname23'], ['billy', 'bo3b']]
#should print [2, 1]
```

I have tried to find solutions but the `len()` and `.isalpha()` method is what I think I should use. Any suggestions?

Comment: SO is not meant as a free code writing service.  We help with specific problems that you encounter while programming and which you have already tried to solve yourself.  Consequentially, all questions asked here must demonstrate some research effort and/or attempted solutions.  After that, we will be more than happy to help.

Comment: You are shading `list`, this word is already a python type-object. Assigning it to a value is bad practice.

Comment: Why would you use `isalpha` to tell you if something is a digit? It's going to return false for `"2"`, `"%"`, `"hi0"`, and `"hi!"`.

Answer (score 5):

You have a sub-problem which is how to determine whether a string contains any digits. For that you can try:

```
>>> s = 'myname23'
>>> any(c.isdigit() for c in s)
True
```

Now you want to count the number of elements of your list for which this condition is true; you can try something like this:

```
>>> l = ['hi0', 'myname23', 'billy', 'bo3b']
>>> sum(1 for s in l if any(c.isdigit() for c in s))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list and check each member:

```
total = 0
for member in list:
    if not member.isalpha():
        total += 1
```

or more concisely

```
total = sum(not m.isalpha() for m in list)
```

A couple of other notes; you should probably not name any variables `list` as this conflicts with the builtin function and type that python uses. Also, `isalpha` will only work if you can guarantee that the rest of the characters will be letters, you could use `if any(char.isdigit() for char in member)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic, readable way to do what you want:

```
def count(L):
    answer = 0
    for word in L:
        hasdigit = False
        for char in word:
            if char.isdigit():
                hasdigit = True
        if hasdigit:
            answer += 1
    return answer
```

Output:

```
In [40]: count(L)
Out[40]: 3
```